# What kind of relationship should be?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have two models: `Users` and `Categories`.

I need to get all categories on which user subscribed.

Do, database structure is:

```
User    Category   UserCategory
___     _________  __________
id      id | name  category_id user_id
```

**Category model is:**

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

**User model is:**

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
```

I tried to get all categories on which user subscribed through third table:

```
$categories =  Category::with("user")->where("id", Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

It does not work for me

Comment: `user()` should be `users()`...

Comment: maybe this helps: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all categories which belong to the user, use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$categories = Category::whereHas('users', function($q) use($userId) {
    $q->where('id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Also, make sure table name is `categories_users` and define `users` relationship like this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Where to define `public function users()`?

Comment: @Darama in the `Category` model. Yes, the `categories()` relationship is correct. But you should remove `user()` relationship and put `users()` instead.

Comment: @Darama as far as I remember it uses `where exists` and yes, it is good way to check relationship existance.

Comment: How to add new category for user?

Comment: `$user->categories()->attach($categoryID);` you can find plenty of infos here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships